# What are the benefits of using class when defining a dataloader in Pytorch?

Tags: python, oop, pytorch, computer-vision, pytorch-dataloader

I have the following dataloader below:

```
def load_dataset(size_batch, size):
    data_path = "/home/bledc/dataset/test_set/crops_BSD"
    transformations = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Grayscale(num_output_channels=1),
        transforms.ToTensor()
        ])

    train_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(
        root=data_path,
        transform=transformations
    )
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=size_batch,
        shuffle=True,
        num_workers=0,
        drop_last=True
    )
    return train_loader
```

I iterate through it in my training loop with the following:

```
data_loader = load_dataset(batch_size, width)
for data in data_loader:
        model.zero_grad()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        img, _ = data
        img = img.to(device)
```

Can someone explain to me what the benefit would be of writing the load_dataset() function into a class? The reason for this is that I have been using the above template for dataloading from code I found online but it seems that most codebases use `class LoaderName(Dataset)` followed by definiting initial conditions and super().

Thank you.

Comment: In your case, none. As `datasets.ImageFolder` fits your dataset, you don't need to implement anything. There is no need for custom implementation in your case. A class is usually implement when a custom behavior is needed.

Comment: Thanks @Berriel that clears things up. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: There is no need. You can even delete the question if you will.

Answer (score 0):

In the words of @Berriel:

> In your case, none. As datasets.ImageFolder fits your dataset, you
> don't need to implement anything. There is no need for custom
> implementation in your case. A class is usually implement when a
> custom behavior is needed.